# Confluent Kafka .Net Local: Erroneous state

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am aiming to implement Confluent Kafka .Net to push messages to Kafka Server but receives this error: "Confluent.Kafka.ProduceException`2[System.String,System.String]: Local: Erroneous state". How do I solve this?
I find nothing to answer this in confluents documentation.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to share your code? Honestly, I don't understand.